# How to toggle renderable on/off for objects in the 3D View

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

How to select multiple objects in the 3D View window (not the outliner) and toggle their renderability on/off?

Want to select them in 3D View because it's much easier to isolate them quickly there than in the outliner.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or hotkey to restrict rendering in Blender Cycles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the objects in the *3D Viewport* and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. This will hide the selected objects during render operations. To clear the restricted render property from objects, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Do you also know the shortcut keys to toggle visibility?

Comment: @sliver Yes, that would be `H` and `Alt`+`H`. `Alt`+`H` makes all objects, regardless of selection become visible iirc.

Comment: What property does ctrl h correspond to please? I can't see anything change anywhere on the screen when I push this.

Comment: @Richard That changes the `Render Visibility` (which is the same as deselecting the camera icon in the `Outliner`)