# How to "Disable in Renders" on multiple selected objects? 2.93

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I'm trying to disable rendering on various selected Objects in the 3D View.
But the [here mentioned CTRL + H](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58300/how-to-toggle-renderable-on-off-for-objects-in-the-3d-view) only shows me hide collection. Because of the nature of my project the objects are splitted between different collections, so I can't use hide collection.
I also tried to asign a shortcut, but the entry is not shown when rightclicking `Disable in Renders`.
What could I do about it?

Answer (score 6):

- Select all of the objects in 3D view
- In the outliner, hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while clicking the "Disable in Render" toggle on one of the objects.

All of the other selected objects will toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method to hide all except relevant:

- Select objects you **do** want to render (don't forget lights)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Invert selection)
- In the outliner, hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while clicking the "Disable in Render" (camera) toggle on one of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + [image] wont work if **Emulate 3 Button Mouse** is enabled, disable it from **Preferences -> Input**.